# Filter data and modifying labels in Seaborn boxplot graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

*EDIT: Removed old question to make it easier to find solution in post.*

[Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) is a Python data visualization library based on [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). To use Seaborn, your data need to be in the [tidy format](https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-tidy-data-how-to-organize-messy-datasets-in-python-with-melt-and-pivotable-functions-5d52daa996c9).

You can use [Pandas DataFrame.loc[]](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-loc/) to filter a dataframe.

In the following example I will (1) load some data from an CSV file into a dataframe, (2) filter that data based on specific values in a column, (3) present that data in a boxplot using Seaborn, and (4) decide the order in which the data is presented and what labels should be used.

Some example data

```
Object,Metric,Score
M11,B2A10,2.7939033333333336
MT1,B2A10,1.287634388888889
MT1,B2A1,7.1535
MT1,B2A2,2.2441833333333334
MT1,B2A3,3.3787333333333334
MT1,B2A4,2.50297
MT1,B2A5,1.4254989999999998
MT1,B2A6,2.91325
MT1,B2A7,1.24806
MT1,B2A8,2.08797725
MT1,B2A9,1.208722
```

## Import libraries and modules

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
```

## Set seaborn style

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="colorblind")
```

## Load data and generate a list of items we want to filter

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv") 

list = ["B2A10", "B2A1"]
```

## Filter data using .loc and place into new dataframe

```
filtered_data = data.loc[data['Metric'].isin(list)]
```

## Generate a boxplot using the filtered data

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax = sns.boxplot(x='Metric', y='Length', data=samples, order=["B2A1", "B2A10"])
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="Metric", y="Length", data=samples, color=".25", order=["B2A1", "B2A10"])
ax.set_xlabel('Label X-Axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Label Y-Axis')
plt.title('Title',fontsize=16)
labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
labels[0] = 'Sample 1'
labels[1] = 'Sample 2'
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

The final graph should look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solutions to both problems.

(1) The first solution is to simply filters the items I want from the original data and save as a new data file. I think this is suboptimal but works for my purposes. I think it would be much more efficient to filter items directly based on what is presented in the graph.

```
# Load list data

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Define items

items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

# Filter items using Pandas isin() function

items_1_3 = data[data.Column.isin(items)]
items_1_3.to_csv('data_1_3.csv', index=False)
```

(2) I found a way to change the labels of the graph based on their position (remember Python starts to count with 0, not 1). I add this code directly after where I have defined my graph.

```
labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()] 
labels[0] = 'one' 
labels[1] = 'two' 
labels[2] = 'three' 
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Hope someone will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer both yur question in the following.

1) To sort the values in the plot (for instance sorting by `Score`) you can first sort `Metric` (which you are using as `order` parameter for the boxplot) by  'Score' doing the following:

```
sorted_order = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(score_tidy.Score, score_tidy.Metric))]
```

Then pass `order=sorted_order` to you boxplot call.

2) To change the xticks labels of any matplotlib-based plot (e.g. those generated through seaborn) you can get the handle of your axes (taking the current one in the following through `plt.gca()`) and do this:

```
plt.gca().set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(sorted_order)), sorted_order)
```

This way you will get your xticks labels from `Metrics`, sorted according to `Score`.

Comment: The first answer is very helpful and I will probably find this useful somewhere, but not the answer I needed. I do not need to sort by score, but by range (example I would want the graph to show only items B2A2, B2A3, B2A4, B2A5). Preferentially, I should be able to remove certain items from the graph. The second answer does not answer the question as I do not see how this allows me t change the labels for each item on the X-axis (example I would like item B2A1 to be named "Control 1").

Comment: @ChristerEdvardsson for the first question: it does not matter what you want to sort on, the strategy I employed will work. Obviously, if you exchange `score_tidy.Metric` with any other array with the same length this will work. Not sure what you mean with 'range' but if you have a 'range' array just exchange `score_tidy.Metric` with it..Same for the second question, if you have any array of xticks labels then using the same approach I used in my answer for example: `plt.gca().set_xticks(np.arange(0, 3), ['Control1', 'Control2', 'Control3'])` will do what you wanted :)

Comment: But wouldn't sorted_order require me to compare items in different columns (which I do not want to do)?